# Does bitnami kafka support Openshift routes?

Tags: apache-kafka, routes, openshift, bitnami

I have been trying to access my Kafka broker outside the Openshift cluster, but it's not allowing me. I have setup the required Openshift route and pointed it to my kafka service.
I tried looking it over internet, but everytime I ended up with an article pointing to strimzi operator / AMQ Stream operator to achieve this functionality.
I am wondering now, does bitnami kafka even supports routes or not ? I could not find any documentation around this.
Could anyone help me point to right direction ?

Comment: What do you have against using Strimzi?

Answer (score 0):

While I haven't used Bitnami Kafka, binary protocols (like Kafka) are typically going to require loadbalancers/nodeports rather than ingresses/routes.

From the [Router docs](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/architecture/networking/routes.html):

Routers support the following protocols:
HTTP
HTTPS (with SNI)
WebSockets
TLS with SNI